# Does wxWebView support relative paths?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Please take a look at the following minimal code:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// headers
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// For compilers that support precompilation, includes "wx/wx.h".
#include "wx/wxprec.h"

// for all others, include the necessary headers (this file is usually all you
// need because it includes almost all "standard" wxWidgets headers)
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
    #include "wx/wx.h"
#endif

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// resources
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#if wxUSE_WEBVIEW_IE
    #include <wx/msw/webview_ie.h>
#endif
#include <wx/webview.h>
#include <wx/filesys.h>
#include <wx/mstream.h>

struct WxHtmlFSHandler : public wxWebViewHandler
{
    std::string html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;"
        "charset=UTF-8'>\n<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0'>"
        "</head><body>"
        "<h1>This is a test</h1>"
        "<a href=\"logo?2\"><img width=\"50%\" src=\"../pic1.png\"></a>"
        "<a href=\"logo?4\"><img width=\"50%\" src=\"pic2.png\"></a></body></html>";
    WxHtmlFSHandler( const wxString& scheme ) : wxWebViewHandler( scheme ) {}

    wxFSFile* GetFile( const wxString& uri ) override
    {
        // handle uri here
        if( uri.Contains("test.html") )
            return new wxFSFile( new wxMemoryInputStream( html.data(), html.size() ), uri, wxT( "text/html" ), ""
              #if wxUSE_DATETIME
                , wxDateTime::Now()
              #endif
            );
    };
};

// Define a new application type, each program should derive a class from wxApp
class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    // override base class virtuals
    // ----------------------------

    // this one is called on application startup and is a good place for the app
    // initialization (doing it here and not in the ctor allows to have an error
    // return: if OnInit() returns false, the application terminates)
    virtual bool OnInit() wxOVERRIDE;
};

// Define a new frame type: this is going to be our main frame
class MyFrame : public wxFrame, public wxBitmap
{
public:
    // ctor(s)
    MyFrame(const wxString& title);
    wxWebView* myWeb = nullptr;
};

// Create a new application object: this macro will allow wxWidgets to create
// the application object during program execution (it's better than using a
// static object for many reasons) and also implements the accessor function
// wxGetApp() which will return the reference of the right type (i.e. MyApp and
// not wxApp)
wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);

// ============================================================================
// implementation
// ============================================================================

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// the application class
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// 'Main program' equivalent: the program execution "starts" here
bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    // call the base class initialization method, currently it only parses a
    // few common command-line options but it could be do more in the future
    if ( !wxApp::OnInit() )
        return false;

    // create the main application window
    MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame("Minimal wxWidgets App");
    
    // and show it (the frames, unlike simple controls, are not shown when
    // created initially)
    frame->Show(true);

    // success: wxApp::OnRun() will be called which will enter the main message
    // loop and the application will run. If we returned false here, the
    // application would exit immediately.
    return true;
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// main frame
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// frame constructor
MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString& title)
       : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title)
{
    myWeb = wxWebView::New( this, wxID_ANY, wxWebViewDefaultURLStr );
    myWeb->RegisterHandler( wxSharedPtr< wxWebViewHandler >( new WxHtmlFSHandler( "myScheme" ) ) );
    if( myWeb && !myWeb->IsBusy() )
        myWeb->LoadURL( "myScheme:test.html" );
}
```

If you set a breakpoint inside `"GetFile"` function, you can see that I receive `"myScheme:pic1.png"` instead of `"myScheme:../pic1.png"`. I am wondering why this happens and how  I can fix that. Of course I can fix my string but that's the worst case scenario. In addition, you can see that I used "LoadURL" instead of "SetPage". If I use the later, nothing loads!

wxWidget version 3.1.5 and Win 10 and Internet Explorer 11 Engine

Comment: wx version? OS? Backend?

Comment: @Igor 3.1.5 and Win 10

Comment: Do you use IE, Edge or Chromium backend?

Comment: @Igor I use IE backend version 11

Comment: It's so strange that no one knows or cares about this library. I am really considering switching to Qt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to deal with problem. I should load the page like this:

```
myWeb->LoadURL( "myScheme:a/b/c/test.html" );
```

In this way, if I have a relative path, e.g. `../pic2.png`, I receive `myScheme:a/b/pic2.png` and if I don't have any relative path, I receive the whole path `myScheme:a/b/c/pic2.png`

So I have to define how many levels of relative path I want in my code. I don't like this hack because it does not support all cases but it's at least a workaround.